# How should I structure my post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

For the site I am making, I have a few post types: News, Events, Projects, Placements. Each one of these post types will need its own archive page, accessible through the navigation. I am able to create these post types using the Types plugin, but my question is how do I create a archive page for them? I can't figure out what the URL will be. `/projects` for the post type with slug `projects` gives me nothing.

I think I understand how the templates for custom post types work (`archive-{post-slug}.php`), but I don't know how to make these pages accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[When a post type is registered](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type), you need to at least set `has_archive` to true. This will use the post type name as the slug for archive. You can also specify a string representing the slug for `has_archive`:

```
'has_archive' => 'projects'
```

This should be accessible under Type's advanced settings, [according to their documentation](http://wp-types.com/documentation/user-guides/create-a-custom-post-type/#2.5).

Comment: I've got that set to true. Still can't access it via `/projects`, though? Not sure if I'm supposed to be able to?

Comment: `has_archive` is checked. It says this below: `Allow custom post type to have index page.
Default: not set.`

Comment: I'm using Types because I find the WordPress API very confusing!

Comment: I'm not familiar with how Types works, so it may be a question for their support. If the post type is registered as `projects`, then setting `has_archive` to true *should* make the archive available at that slug.

Comment: Got it in the end. Forgot to actually make a template! Now I need help with this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60732/listing-and-accessing-categories-for-a-custom-post-type