# Listing and accessing categories for a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I have two post types: Projects and Events. I want each of these post types to have their own categories: Upcoming and Past.

I have an archive page displaying the posts in these types. However, on this page I want to *list the categories* that this post type has. I've done some research but to no avail.

I then want that list to link to the category, showing the posts in the category for the current post type (Projects or Events).

So I have two questions:

1. How do I generate the list of categories with links?
2. What would the URL be for showing a category in a custom post type? I've tried creating a category.php page and accessing `/projects/upcoming/` but again, to no avail.